# Hadoop does not understand Composite Keys are equal

Tags: hadoop

My data set has this format:

```
userID mediaID rating
```

I'd like to find the co-occurence of any pair of mediaIDs that receive a rating higher than a threshold across all users. To do this, I followed several examples to implement a composite key. I wrote a PairKey class which stores a unique pair, implemented compareTo and overridden hashCode and equals...

```
  public static class PairKey implements WritableComparable<PairKey> {

    private Integer lowID;
    private Integer highID;


    public PairKey() {

        this.lowID = -1;
        this.highID = -1;

    }

    public PairKey(Integer one, Integer two) {
        //should be impossible
        if (one.equals(two)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Cannot have a pair key with identical IDs");
        }
        if (one < two) {
            lowID = one;
            highID = two;
        }
        else {
            lowID = two;
            highID = one;
        }
    }

    public Integer getLowID() {
        return lowID;
    }

    public Integer getHighID() {
        return highID;
    }

    public void setLowID(Integer _lowID) {
        lowID = _lowID;
    }

    public void setHighID(Integer _highID) {
        highID = _highID;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(PairKey other) {
        int _lowCompare = lowID.compareTo(other.getLowID());
        if (_lowCompare != 0) {
            return _lowCompare;
        }
        int _highCompare = highID.compareTo(other.getHighID());
        return _highCompare;
    }

    @Override
    public void write(DataOutput dataOutput) throws IOException {
        dataOutput.writeInt(lowID.intValue());
        dataOutput.writeInt(highID.intValue());
    }

    @Override
    public void readFields(DataInput dataInput) throws IOException {
        lowID = new Integer(dataInput.readInt());
        highID = new Integer(dataInput.readInt());
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "<" + lowID + ", " + highID + ">";
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {

        if (this == o) {
            return true;
        }
        if ( o == null || this.getClass() != o.getClass()) {
            return false;
        }

        PairKey other = (PairKey) o;

        //compare fields
        if (this.lowID != null ?    this.lowID.equals(other.getLowID()) == false  : other.getLowID() != null) return false;
        if (this.highID != null ?   this.highID.equals(other.getHighID()) == false : other.getHighID() != null) return false;

        return true;
    }


    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int _lowHash = this.lowID.hashCode();
        int _highHash = this.highID.hashCode();
        return 163 * (_lowHash ) + _highHash;
    }
}
```

Here is my mapper code, I store all movieIDs that passed the threshold in a set per user, then emit all the possible pairs in this set:

```
    public static class PairMapper extends Mapper<Text, Text, PairKey, IntWritable> {

    private Map<Integer, SortedSet<Integer>> temp = new HashMap<Integer, SortedSet<Integer>>();
    private IntWritable one = new IntWritable(1);
    private PairKey _key = new PairKey();

    public void map(Text key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        Integer userID = new Integer(key.toString());
        String[] vals = value.toString().split("\t");
        String _movieID = vals[0];
        String _rating = vals[1];
        Integer movieID = new Integer(_movieID);
        Integer rating = new Integer(_rating);
        if (rating > 3) {
            SortedSet candidates  = temp.get(userID);
            if (candidates == null) {
                candidates = new TreeSet<Integer>();
            }
            candidates.add(movieID);
            temp.put(userID, candidates);

        }
    }//map

    public void cleanup(Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

        for (Map.Entry<Integer, SortedSet<Integer>> e : temp.entrySet()) {

            SortedSet<Integer> _set = e.getValue();
            Integer [] arr = _set.toArray(new Integer[_set.size()]);
            for (int i = 0 ; i < arr.length-1 ; i++) {
                for (int j = i+1 ; j < arr.length ; j++) {
                    _key.setLowID(arr[i]);
                    _key.setHighID(arr[j]);
                    context.write(_key, one);
                }//for j

            }//for i




        }



    }//cleanup



}//PairMapper
```

This is my reducer:

```
   public static class PairReducer extends Reducer<PairKey, Iterable<IntWritable>, Text, IntWritable> {

    public void reduce(PairKey key, Iterable<IntWritable> vals, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        int sum = 0;
        for (IntWritable val : vals) {
            sum+= val.get();
        }//for
        IntWritable result = new IntWritable(sum);
        context.write(new Text(key.toString()), result);
    } //reduce

}
```

and this is my driver main method:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Configuration conf = new Configuration();
    String[] otherArgs = new GenericOptionsParser(conf, args).getRemainingArgs();

    if (otherArgs.length != 2) {
        System.err.println("Usage: moviepairs <in> <out>");
        System.exit(2);
    }

    //CONFIGURE THE JOB
    Job job = new Job(conf, "movie pairs");

    job.setJarByClass(MoviePairs.class);

   job.setSortComparatorClass(CompositeKeyComparator.class);
   job.setPartitionerClass(NaturalKeyPartitioner.class);
   job.setGroupingComparatorClass(NaturalKeyGroupingComparator.class);

    //map-reduce classes
    job.setMapperClass(PairMapper.class);
    job.setCombinerClass(PairReducer.class);
    job.setReducerClass(PairReducer.class);


    //key-val classes
    job.setMapOutputKeyClass(PairKey.class);
    job.setMapOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);
    job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    job.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);


    job.setInputFormatClass(KeyValueTextInputFormat.class);
    FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(otherArgs[0]));
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(otherArgs[1]));

    System.exit(job.waitForCompletion(true)? 0 :1);

}
```

I expect to get this in my reducer:

```
pair <1,2>: [1,1,1]
```

but instead the reducer does not seem to understand the equality of pairs. Outputting this instead:

```
pair<1,2>: [1]
pair<1,2>: [1]
pair<1,2>: [1]
```

Not sure what I'm missing there. As you can see I've tried several things like adding a custom sorter (which I don't believe I need and using a Grouping comparator, custom partitioner), but I think simply overriding hashcode/equals should account for that? (not sure). All the examples I found online seem to follow this and they all seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

As usual with those beginner questions, the problem was completely irrelevant. I had screwed up the Reducer interface. 
Instead of `<KEYIN, VALIN...>` I was doing `<KEYIN, ITERABLE<VALIN>....>`